# Launching task in Spring Cloud Dataflow with application properties

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-dataflow

I have a Spring Cloud Task in SCDF that launches successfully with the task definition:

```
some-task --some.property=test
```

I'd like to set the `some.property` property on task launch instead though. I thought I could do this by setting the deployment property `app.*.some.property=test`, but this doesn't work with either the local or cloudfoundry task launchers/deployers.

The above deployment property works with streams, but not tasks. Is it suppose to work with tasks, if not, why?

Comment: It should on Tasks, too. We have added support for it in recent releases, though. Could you confirm the version of SCT, SCDF, and the custom-apps?

Comment: @SabbyAnandan We're currently using SCT 2.0.0.RELEASE and SCDF 1.7.0.RELEASE, the task app is based on Spring Boot 2.0.4. Digging through the cloudfoundry deployer I assumed this was [the method handling it](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-deployer-cloudfoundry/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/deployer/spi/cloudfoundry/CloudFoundryAppDeployer.java#L274). But it doesn't refer to the `app.*` properties at all, so I'm not sure where to look for the functionality.  I'll try to put together a little POC to reproduce the issue, if that'd help

Comment: Thanks. You're almost on the latest and I'm pretty sure the improvements are already in that version. The core improvements pertaining to the parser, properties, and orchestration are typically handled in the SCDF itself. See [docs-1](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/1.7.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#_passing_properties_to_the_child_tasks) and [docs-2](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/1.7.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#api-guide-resources-task-executions-launching-request-structure) for a few samples.

Comment: If you continue to see this behavior, yes, it'd be great to review a reprodcible sample.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. We can pass properties while launching a Task.

Task applications required same Database connections which Dataflow server uses to log the steps and executions. I deployed below task in local SCDF.

```
task create --definition "timestmp_custm  --timestamp.format=\"dd.MM.yyyy\"" --name  taskTimestmp2

task launch taskTimestmp2 --arguments "--spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb  --spring.datasource.username=root --spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver"
```